# Finding probabilities in a binomial distribuion

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

$100$ people are each given a lottery ticket and each of those tickets have the probability $p$ of winning a prize (independent of others)

To find the probability that exactly $10$ people win a prize, I have tried to find $P(X=10)$ using the binomial distribution formula. I know $X = 10$ and $n = 100$. But how can I know what $p$ is, when it isn't mentioned in the question?

Comment: Can you leave the answer in terms of $p$?

Comment: I believe the question is asking for p to be evaluated? is that possible?

Comment: I don't that is possible either with the given information. Is there no other information in the question through which $p$ can be inferred?

Comment: hmm, no thats the complete question. It does say that Each ticket has "probability p of winning a prize". Can we imply that it means each ticket has the same probability?

Comment: We can infer that all tickets have the same probability of winning, but that doesn't tell us what $p$ is.  I think the answer is ${100\choose10}p^{10}(1-p)^{90}$

Comment: Right, that was what i had in mind too. Appreciate the input guys!